# iOS8 custom keyboard issues

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I'm working on iOS 8 custom keyboard extension right now, and there are some issues that I cannot figure out.

First, I think the `UITextInputDelegate` Methods are not working as I expected.

Does this sound right: `selectionWillChange:` and `selectionDidChange:` methods should be called when user long-presses typing area? And `textWillChange:` and `textDidChange:` methods should be called whenever the text is literally changing?

Actually, what I observed is that, when I changed selection in text input area, `textWillChange:` and `textDidChange:` are called, and I cannot get a clue that the other two methods are called in what condition. If anyone knows about the usage of these delegate methods, please let me know.

Second, I know the `playInputClick:` method can be used to virtualize keyboard click sound in custom keyboard. As this is applicable in a normal situation, I found it impossible to apply in iOS 8 custom keyboard extension. My app consists of one keyboard view controller, and custom view that subclasses UIView is added to this view controller. My approach is that `UIInputViewAudioFeedback` delegate is declared in this custom view, enableInputClicksWhenVisible method is returning `YES`, class method that calls `[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick]` is set, then this method is called wherever the keyboard sound is needed: which is not working at all.

Is my approach is wrong in any way? If anyone has succeeded in using `playInputClick` method, please share your wisdom.

Thank you

Comment: Consider splitting this into two separate questions.

Comment: Answered your first question in the separate question you posted on SO (http://stackoverflow.com/q/25158161/2057171). As for `playInputClick` it is disabled on custom keyboards at this point in time, you have to use custom audio playback.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw which custom audio playback approach have you had success with in the KeyboardExtension? Those we've tried don't seem to work outside of the simulator.

Comment: @wxs I had it working at one point after gold master was released, it was laggy, but it's gotten better depending on the file type you use, but I no longer have the code /: I'm sorry. But don't lose hope, there is a way I can guarantee it because I've seen it work haha, good luck! Bookmark this link and come share an answer with us once you figure it out!

Answer (score 6):

It is best to play the Audio on a queue rather than in the UI key handler

```
func playPressKeySound() {
    let PRESS_KEY_DEFAULT_SOUND_ID: SystemSoundID = 1104
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PRESS_KEY_DEFAULT_SOUND_ID)
        }
}
```

NOTE: this only works if the keyboard has Full Access switched on, so best test there is full access before calling, otherwise the keyboard can suffer long pauses.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, try AudioServicesPlaySystemSound

```
#define PRESS_KEY_DEFAULT_SOUND_ID 1104

- (void)playPressKeySound {
    if (self.openPressSound) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(PRESS_KEY_DEFAULT_SOUND_ID);
    }
}
```