# UITextInputDelegate methods not functioning correctly

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I'm working on iOS 8 custom keyboard extension right now, and there are some issues in using *UITextInputDelegate* Methods.

Does this right: *selectionWillChange:* and *selectionDidChange:* methods should be called when user long-presses typing area? And *textWillChange:* and *textDidChange:* methods should be called whenever the text is literally changing?

Actually, what I observed is that, when I changed selection in text input area, textWillChange: and textDidChange: are called, and I cannot get a clue that the other two methods are called in what condition. If anyone knows about the usage of these delegate methods, please let me know.

Comment: Been pulling hairs over this too. I cannot get `selectionWillChange` `selectionDidChange` called. It is not clear from the (modest) documentation when exactly is it supposed to be called. _"when the selection has changed"_ is not exactly specific. I tried moving cursor, select, move selection, copy, paste. Did I miss something??

Comment: Totally agree. I read the documentation a hundred of times and still cannot figure out any clues.

Comment: @bauerMusic Got you a working solution, granted it isn't with the methods you wanted. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25225419/2057171

Comment: Bug. Still not working, but thankfully there *are* work arounds

Answer (score 5):

It's not working for me either... what I am currently doing is just using `textWillChange` and `textDidChange` which does get called, as you mentioned, when you change your selection... (they get called **BEFORE** and **AFTER**) 
And then comparing the: 
`self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput`
`self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput` 
From **BEFORE** (textWillChange) to the **AFTER** (textDidChange) to see if selection range or length changed at all.

---

Something like this (set the 4 NSStrings below in your .h file of course... haven't tested this exact snippet because I wrote it from scratch just now on SO.com but I'm sure the principle works if I made any errors)

```
- (void)textWillChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {
    beforeStringOfTextBehindCursor = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput;
    beforeStringOfTextAfterCursor = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput;
}

- (void)textDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {
    afterStringOfTextBehindCursor = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput;
    afterStringOfTextAfterCursor = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput;

    BOOL didSelectionChange = NO;

    if (![beforeStringOfTextBehindCursor isEqualToString:afterStringOfTextBehindCursor]) {
        didSelectionChange = YES;
    }

    if (![beforeStringOfTextAfterCursor isEqualToString:afterStringOfTextAfterCursor]) {
        didSelectionChange = YES;
    }

    if (didSelectionChange) {
        NSLog(@"Selection Changed!");
    }   
}
```

Comment: I filed a bug report to Apple a week ago and got a "test case" request from them, which I sent recently. Either this is not working as it should, or I missunderstood the function of the delegate, to which case, the documentations should be clearer and more specific.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with the functions specified in the UITextInput protocol not being called. The reason as far as I can discern is due to the fact that the inputDelegate is set at runtime. According to the ios docs:

*The UIKit provides a private text input delegate, which it assigns at runtime to the inputDelegate property of the object whose class adopts the UITextInput protocol.* [link](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInputDelegate/textWillChange:)

The fix which works in my case is to reset the inputDelegate in the function:

```
textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
     replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

by the following line:

```
[myUITextField setInputDelegate:self];
```

where *self* implements the UITextInputDelegate protocol.

Comment: This answer is unclear, and appears to be wrong. The question is how to activate this protocol within an iOS8 keyboard extension, which functions only with the limited UITextInputDelegate methods. I can't find any UITextField available to set an input delegate to, or any way to override shouldChangeCharactersinRange.

Comment: I agree with Randy Hill. May be in a parallel universe there is UITextInput delegate available for this imaginary UITextfield the op is talking about, sadly not in this universe.